# Divergent sum proof verification

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, solution-verification

Let $(S_n)^\infty_{n=1}$ be the sequence of partial sums of $(a_n)^\infty_{n=1}$.
Prove that if $a_{n+1} = S_n^2-S_n+5$ for every $n\in N$ then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ is divergent.

My proof is:

Assume by contradiction that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n$ is convergent to $L\in\mathbb{R}$.
So $\lim_{n\to \infty}a_n=0$. Then
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n+1}=\lim_{n\to\infty}(S_n^2-S_n+5) =L^2-L+5= 0$$
and
$$L_{1,2}= \frac{1\pm \sqrt{1-20}}{2} = 0$$
which gives no real solutions.
Contradiction.

Does the proof suffice?

Comment: You forgot to define $S_n$ and $a$.

Comment: You cannot conclude $S_n^2-S_n+5=0$. However, you can conclude that a subsequence of the $S_n$'s tends to one of the roots of $x^2-x+5$, which is absurd (if we *add* the condition that the $a_n$ are real, or conclude this by induction if also $a_1=S_0^2-S_0+5=5$ is assumed to hold)

Comment: When you write $a^n$, do you mean to write $a_n$?

Comment: @lulu Yes, it was a typo

Answer (score 3):

From $S_0=0$, we find $a_1\in\Bbb R$ and then by induction that all $S_n$ and all $a_n$ are $\in \Bbb R$. This makes
$$ a_{n+1}=S_n^2-S_n+5=(S_n-\tfrac12)^2+4\tfrac34\ge4\tfrac34$$
whereas a convergent series necessarily has $a_n\to 0$.